# OSX Docker Desktop file sharing between host and containers doesn't work with /etc/hosts via docker-compose

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose, hosts

```
  service:
    volumes:
      - ~/.gitconfig:/root/.gitconfig
      - ~/.pgpass:/root/.pgpass
      - $SSH_AUTH_SOCK:/ssh-agent
      - /etc/hosts:/etc/hosts
    environment:
      - SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/ssh-agent
```

At running i try to modify /etc/hosts inside of container

```
#!/bin/sh

alias_host_name="db"
container_ip=$(hostname -I|awk -F\  '{ print $(NF) }')

echo "Set route: $alias_host_name -> $container_ip"
grep -q $alias_host_name /etc/hosts
hosts_have_alias=$(echo $?)
if [ $hosts_have_alias -ne 0 ]; then
    # no data for alias_host_name
    echo "$container_ip $alias_host_name" >> /etc/hosts
else
    # data for alias_host_name already exists
    cp /etc/hosts ~/hosts.new

    reg_exp_ip="((1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}(1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])"
    sed -ri "s/$reg_exp_ip \t$alias_host_name/$container_ip $alias_host_name/" ~/hosts.new
    sed -ri "s/$reg_exp_ip $alias_host_name/$container_ip $alias_host_name/" ~/hosts.new

    cat ~/hosts.new > /etc/hosts
fi
```

so i expect that /etc/hosts will have new line

it works fine at linux

thx for help!

Answer (score 0):

Docker manages the `/etc/hosts` file for you.  You can't provide it in an image or bind-mount it.  This is also true of `/etc/resolv.conf`, and it's part of how Docker provides a network environment for a container.

For what you're showing you don't need `/etc/hosts` at all.  If you're running the containers in Docker Compose, [it automatically provides DNS resolution between containers](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) so a host name `db` refers to the container that's declared as `db:` in the `docker-compose.yml` file.  This is provided out-of-the-box; you don't need to do anything at all for this functionality to work.

If you need to give an alternate name to a container, you can declare [`aliases:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#aliases) for it in the `docker-compose.yml` file.  It'd be a little unusual to need this, though.

Heavily relying on `/etc/hosts` usually isn't a best practice.  Keeping hosts files in sync across multiple environments is difficult, and in your example where you're shadowing a host name that already exists, the behavior can be different in different programs (depending on whether it uses the system resolver or only true DNS).  If you must, though, you can specify [`extra_hosts:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extra_hosts) in the `docker-compose.yml` file to have Docker set it up for you.

Comment: May be i have different case, i need to have access to container from host machine by alias and container has dynamic IP. So my workaround helps me to have aliases in /etc/hosts at my machine. I need to use alias in URL path to open web. It really works at linux, but i need compatibility with OSX (on MACOS /etc/host is just copying for now, i cannot edit host's version of file)

Comment: You can't directly access the container IP address on OS X, at all, and doing it on Linux isn't really encouraged.  But you can reliably access a port you published with `ports:` on the host's IP address (or `localhost` if you're specifically outside a container on the same system) on all platforms, and that's the standard way to access a container.

Comment: i mean that i use URL like http://container.test.com:80 to access web interface, i can do it by IP, but project has some logic based on hostname. I really need to use /etc/hosts aliases to connect on container's ports